# Log Jersey entity as JSON as response

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey

I'm a Jersey newbie and I need to log the JSON response. I wish to take the entity and convert it to JSON exactly as done by the Jersey framework does (same mapper, etc.). Is there a way to extract its mapper (and call, for example, its writeValueAsString)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify which package you use for producing the JSON response (neither you explain much about your jersey server), but I will assume you use `Jackson`.

You have some tracing in Jersey, take a look [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#tracing), but as fas as I know it does not do what you need.

But first of all you should implement a `LoggingFilter`,

```
public class YourLoggingFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext, final ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {
        ...

    }

}
```

And I assume you extend the `ResourceConfig` class to add resources, you need to add the new filter here:

```
public class YourApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public YourApplication() {
        super();

        register(YourAuthenticationRequestFilter.class, Priorities.AUTHENTICATION);
        register(YourExceptionMapper.class);
        register(YourLoggingFilter.class);

        packages("...");
    }
}
```

And finally, a simple way to log your response inside `YourLoggingFilter` would be (here I assume `Jackson`, but this is just an example, I don't know what logger you are using, but don't open a file every time you do a request!!!)

```
Object obj = responseContext.getEntity();
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
File file = new File("...");
try {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    om.writeValue(out, obj);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // this could fail but you don't want your request to fail
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, and basically I have accomplished something quite similar, but you "fell" exactly where I have "fallen": focusing on the implementation of YourLoggingFilter you are using the ObjectMapper, but I wish to use the exact same mapper as the Jersey infra. You are assuming that Jersey is using that, but what if tomorrow someone will change it and this logging code is still using a specific implementation?
specifically, I found out that the actual response trims the null elements while using ObjectMapper doesn't. So here is a difference. How can I use the same mapper as the real response?

Comment: Well, you really need to go into the bowels of the server for doing that, I guess.... In case it helps, take a look to `ServerRuntime` method `writeResponse`, at least in my version, but it seems kind of tough, lots of objects to create. I wonder why you need exactly the same, but it is quite some effort. By the way, if you already had a solution, even if it was incomplete, I would suggest you post it together with your question, that way you avoid somebody building up an answer which you already have... in my case, it didn't take much. Anyhow, only a suggestion. Cheers.

Comment: OK, thanks. I thought there was a simpler way to extract the "same mapper as the response uses". And sorry for confusing you, I meant to ask just for the mapper, assuming I have the ContainerResponseContext, didn't mean to mislead that I don't know how to get that.

Comment: Thank you. I did not mean that you have to accept the answer. Actually, it is not really an answer to your question (i.e. to the additional aspects of your question). You can "unaccept" it if you want. The only think I was suggesting is that the narrower the questions the better.... And really, it didn't take me much time to write my answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I accepted it as it might help those who don't know how to get the response object to begin with :)