# How to print the Jersey's Xml response

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jersey

How to print the XML response generated from jersey? I need to log the response for info. Is this possible? My service class looks like this:

```js
@Path("/name")
public class AuditoriumService {

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  public List<String> getNames() throws UnrecoverableException {
    List<String> nameList = getNameList();
    
    log.info("Response: Status Code: "+200);
    return nameList;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not print the list? If not then look at marshaller and unmarshaller that you may have specified or if using JAXB then use the method provided for the same.

Comment: You have to use a [LoggingFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2362106/1252603).

Comment: Also you could take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34850858/log-jersey-entity-as-json-as-response/34854130). Uses `LoggingFilter` and `Json`, but you should be able to do something similar.